# Process an array (which updates while processing it) synchronously

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `arr` and I need to run a function on each of its value. However the array is updated by the time the loop process finished processing the array.

For example, `arr` has 1000 usernames, with 10 new usernames per second.

How can you run a sync task on this constantly updating array?

It is also possible that no more usernames get added to the array, so it should have a completion phase. The usernames can then start coming in the array again even if it has been completed, so I will need to handle the re-start of the task as well.

The function that I run on the array elements (usernames) are async, IE there's a `setTimeout` in it.

Comment: You have to have an processed array and unprocessed array, you will process the last element of unprocessed array and add it to the processed array, then remove that element from unprocessed array.

Comment: Is the function you are running on each value updating the array, or is another (unrelated) process doing that? If the latter, please elaborate. What kind of "update" are we talking about here, you only mention "adding"?

Comment: Even if the function you are running is asynchronous, does that even matter? If you start it synchronously on all items (so that 1000 async tasks are running concurrently), what is the problem with the update?

Comment: @Bergi the other function is doing an un-related tasks (db tasks), but I want it to process 1 item (username in my example) at a time. Because if there's a big influx of data coming in, the DB will crash. I prefer to keep the queue under control.

Comment: So the array is just that, a *queue* for your sequential task, and not needed as a data structure for anything else?

Comment: @Bergi -- Right

Answer (score 0):

You could use a queue to have a list of waiting items and complete items.

The guts of the posted code is

```
while (this.queue.length) {
  this.complete.push(this.mapper(this.queue.pop()))
}
```

We are pulling the latest value from the queue, modifying it with the mapper function and adding it to the complete list.

```js
class Queue {
  constructor(queue, mapper) {
    this.queue = queue || []
    this.complete = []
    this.mapper = mapper
    // start running the stack processing
    this.map()
  }
  // start processing the stack
  map() {
    // loop over the stack until it's empty
    while (this.queue.length) {
      this.complete.push(this.mapper(this.queue.pop()))
    }
    console.log('complete processing', this.complete.length, 'items')
  }
  add(val) {
    console.log('add', val)
    // add value to the stack
    this.queue.unshift(val)
    // run the stack processing
    this.map()
  }
  // get the complete stack
  completed() {
    return this.complete
  }
}

// just a random function to modify the stack contents
const toHex = item => {
  const hex = item.toString(16)
  return '0x' + (hex < 10 ? '0' + hex : hex)
}
// instantiate your new stack
const queue = new Queue([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], toHex)

// nothing to see here, it's just to mock up the asynchronous adding 
// of items to the stack
const startTime = Date.now()

const timer = () => {
  const now = Date.now()
  queue.add(now - startTime)
  if (now - startTime < 1000) {
    setTimeout(timer, parseInt(Math.random() * 30))
  }
}
timer()
```

Comment: Do you mean a stack or a queue?

Comment: Probably a better word for it

Comment: No, the two are quite different data structures. Which do you mean?

Comment: don't know sorry mate. Never did CS. I think it's a `queue` cause it's first in first out.

Comment: Yeah, a stack would be lifo, but your implementation is first in first out (add to begin, remove from end)?